# Py2App How to use

Tags: python, macos, py2app

How does one exactly use Py2App, which creates standalone applications for python. I downloaded it, but have no idea what to do next, what to install, etc...

Comment: That's what documentation is for.

Answer (score 2):

All the documentation is here, found with a simple Google search:

http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html

Why not read that first, before you ask other people to spend time helping you out?